# JSR 303 validation in Spring - how to refuse string of number when the field should only accept Integer

Tags: java, json, bean-validation

When I validate a JSON format entity in request body, a number field comes in as a string of number parsable to Integer is accepted as valid. But I want to check it only contains number and refuse any string, parsable or not.

But I think JSR 303 validation does not distinguish numbers or numbers in string.

For example, it should be:

```
{
    "quantity": 1,
    ...
}
```

but when it is:

```
{
    "quantity": "1",
    ...
}
```

no error is detected.

The validation is like:

```
@NotNull(message = "order item quantity is required")
@Digits(integer = Integer.MAX_VALUE, fraction = 0) // only integer
@PositiveOrZero
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Order Item quantity", required = true) // for Swagger UI
@JsonProperty("quantity")
private Integer quantity;
```

Note that `@Pattern` only applies to char sequences.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from creating your own validator that will suit your needs. All you need to do is to create a new custom annotation and provide an implementation of the `ConstraintValidator` interface. With this you can then implement the `isValid` method with all the logic you need to perform your validation actions. I could have a go and provide an example, given that you make your validation requirements a bit more clear (having a hard time understanding exactly what you want to achieve).

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear. Look, in the JSON I could have a number, comes as `12` or `"12"`. As I have Java type `Integer`, I want to fail the validation when the value in JSON is `"12"`, and only `12` passes the validation. What confuses me is that it seems that the standard JSR303 does not distinguish the data type; is this what should we expect when the data comes in JSON?